# PerformanceTune#Huge Table Size

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Looking for a help in PT. 
Attaching the psuedo query..
There are 3 tables used below all are having huge chunk of records 
***t2 ~ 10 million, 
t1 ~ 15 million ,
t3 ~ 8 million*** 
Used Parallel Hints . But not much help in cost.. Cost is shooting to more than  200k

```
(SELECT /*+ parallel (a,8) parallel (b,8)*/  
          DISTINCT B.ACCNT_NUM  
          FROM s1.t1 a, s2.t2 b  
          WHERE a.accnt_num = b.accnt_num  
            AND product_key IN (SELECT product_key FROM s3.t3 WHERE prod_type_cd = 'S')
            AND a.active_flg = 'Y'
            AND a.deleted_flg = 'N'
          GROUP BY B.ACCNT_NUM, a.product_key
          HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)
```

Plan:

```
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT 
| 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | | | | | 1 | PX COORDINATOR | | | | | | | | | | | 
| 2 | PX SEND QC (RANDOM) | :TQ10004 | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,04 | P->S | QC (RAND) | 
| 3 | HASH UNIQUE | | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,04 | PCWP | | 
| 4 | PX RECEIVE | | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,04 | PCWP | |
| 5 | PX SEND HASH | :TQ10003 | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,03 | P->P | HASH | 
|* 6 | FILTER | | | | | | | | Q1,03 | PCWC | | 
| 7 | HASH GROUP BY | | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,03 | PCWP | |      
| 8 | PX RECEIVE | | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,03 | PCWP | | 
| 9 | PX SEND HASH | :TQ10002 | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,02 | P->P | HASH | 
| 10 | HASH GROUP BY | | 1 | 54 | 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,02 | PCWP | |   
|* 11 | HASH JOIN | | 90476 | 4771K| 204K (1)| 00:47:39 | | | Q1,02 | PCWP | | 
| 12 | PX RECEIVE | | 22572 | 462K| 66147 (1)| 00:15:27 | | | Q1,02 | PCWP | | 
| 13 | PX SEND BROADCAST | :TQ10001 | 22572 | 462K| 66147 (1)| 00:15:27 | | | Q1,01 | P->P | BROADCAST | 
|* 14 | TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| table 1 | 22572 | 462K| 66147 (1)| 00:15:27 | | | Q1,01 | PCWP | | 
| 15 | NESTED LOOPS | | 135K| 4893K| 198K (1)| 00:46:19 | | | Q1,01 | PCWP | | 
| 16 | BUFFER SORT | | | | | | | | Q1,01 | PCWC | | 
| 17 | PX RECEIVE | | | | | | | | Q1,01 | PCWP | | 
| 18 | PX SEND BROADCAST | :TQ10000 | | | | | | | | S->P | BROADCAST | 
| 19 | SORT UNIQUE | | 6 | 96 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 | | | | | | 
|* 20 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | table 3 | 6 | 96 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 | | | | | | 
| 21 | PX PARTITION HASH ALL | | 65923 | | 207 (1)| 00:00:03 | 1 | 32 | Q1,01 | PCWC | | 
|* 22 | INDEX RANGE SCAN | I_table1 | 65923 | | 207 (1)| 00:00:03 | 33 | 64 | Q1,01 | PCWP | | 
| 23 | PX BLOCK ITERATOR | | 12M| 201M| 5738 (2)| 00:01:21 | | | Q1,02 | PCWC | | 
| 24 | INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | I_table 2 | 12M| 201M| 5738 (2)| 00:01:21 | | | Q1,02 | PCWP | |
```

Regards

Comment: please post the execution plan. How much time it takes to execute the query?

Comment: how many row it yields? why you group by a.product_key if you need only b.accnt_num?

Comment: Removed Product key in group .Still the Same Cost . But yes if i am grouping by product key the cardinality is getting reduced, BUt without product key it is shooting high.

Comment: Attaching Explain plan

Comment: Explain Plan is very Long so breaking it

Comment: Cost is not very important. I can give you another plan with higher cost and better performance. How many minutes takes to execute the query? How many row yields `SELECT product_key FROM s3.t3 WHERE prod_type_cd = 'S'`? How many rows yields `select * from s1.t1 where a.active_flg = 'Y' AND a.deleted_flg = 'N'`?

Comment: Do you have an index on a.product_key?

Comment: Plan hash value: 2824021685

Comment: SELECT product_key FROM s3.t3 WHERE prod_type_cd = 'S'  -- 6 records,   In table 1 we have composite index on product key there are other columns also in there.. In table 2 there is no index ..     select * from s1.t1 where a.active_flg = 'Y' AND a.deleted_flg = 'N'   -- Will give count in a while as it is still executing

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the cost. You need to provide the query you're running, the explain plan for that query a list of indexes on the tables including what columns they're in and the selectivity of the columns in your WHERE statement. This is the _minimum_ required to get a decent answer. You also need to tell us whether or not this is running quick enough, Ignore the cost; if it's running quick enough then you're fine but "quick" is completely dependent on the user.

Comment: As Ben said, we still need the plan. An ideea would be to eliminate the parallel hints, and the plan will be smaller. Then update the question with the plan.

Comment: Thanks Ben .. Query i have attaached above in my question ..and index is on account number which we have already joined. and yes for product key which we are using in inline query (SELECT /*+ parallel (a,8) parallel (b,8)*/  
          DISTINCT B.ACCNT_NUM  
          FROM s1.t1 a, s2.t2 b  
          WHERE a.accnt_num = b.accnt_num  
            AND product_key(idx yes) IN (SELECT product_key ( idx no)FROM s3.t3 WHERE prod_type_cd = 'S')
            AND a.active_flg = 'Y'
            AND a.deleted_flg = 'N'
          GROUP BY B.ACCNT_NUM, a.product_key
          HAVING COUNT (*) > 1)

Comment: Thanks Florin, I have removed parallel hints..But stil its huge. .Do we have any Attachment option here..?

Comment: first part : |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                                |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |

Comment: |   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                          | :TQ10004                 |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,04 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                                 |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                                 |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |

Comment: |   5 |      PX SEND HASH                              | :TQ10003                 |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|*  6 |       FILTER                                   |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|   7 |        HASH GROUP BY                           |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |

Comment: |   8 |         PX RECEIVE                             |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ10002                 |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|  10 |           HASH GROUP BY                        |                          |     1 |    54 |   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |

Comment: |* 11 |            HASH JOIN                           |                          | 90476 |  4771K|   204K  (1)| 00:47:39 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  12 |             PX RECEIVE                         |                          | 22572 |   462K| 66147   (1)| 00:15:27 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              PX SEND BROADCAST                 | :TQ10001                 | 22572 |   462K| 66147   (1)| 00:15:27 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->P | BROADCAST  |

Comment: |* 14 |               TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| table 1                  | 22572 |   462K| 66147   (1)| 00:15:27 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |                NESTED LOOPS                    |                          |   135K|  4893K|   198K  (1)| 00:46:19 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |                 BUFFER SORT                    |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |

Comment: |  17 |                  PX RECEIVE                    |                          |       |       |            |          |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  18 |                   PX SEND BROADCAST            | :TQ10000                 |       |       |            |          |       |       |        | S->P | BROADCAST  |
|  19 |                    SORT UNIQUE                 |                          |     6 |    96 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |

Comment: |* 20 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | table 3                  |     6 |    96 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |        |      |            |
|  21 |                 PX PARTITION HASH ALL          |                          | 65923 |       |   207   (1)| 00:00:03 |     1 |    32 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|* 22 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN              | I_table1                 | 65923 |       |   207   (1)| 00:00:03 |    33 |    64 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |

Comment: |  23 |             PX BLOCK ITERATOR                  |                          |    12M|   201M|  5738   (2)| 00:01:21 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
|  24 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN              | I_table 2                |    12M|   201M|  5738   (2)| 00:01:21 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |

Comment: Apologize for multiple comments as i am not able to paste fully broke it and pasted it starting from part1

Comment: You need to *edit your question* to include additional information.  There's no way we can interpret your plan when it's strewn across multiple comments.  Besides, comments are intended to be transitory

Comment: I've edited the query from your comments. You may remove the comments. And if needed, update the plan there.

Comment: The plan in the question is essentially useless as all the formatting/indention is lost. Please edit the question and add a properly formatted execution plan. You also need to add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and the definition of all indexes available on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

So the eye is drawn to this line of the Explain Plan:

```
|* 20 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | table 3 | 6 | 96 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 | | | | | |
```

The optimizer on the other hand thinks it has *six* rows, and so regards it as a very cheap operation.  The OP says that `t3` has ~ 8 million rows.  A Full Table Scan of that will be pretty expensive.

The optimizer is clever but relies on accurate table and index statistics.  It seems a good place to start would be a review of the pertinent statistics, and [refreshing the ones which are inaccurate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general.htm#ADMIN11525).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#PFGRF003).